# Wired or Wireless cant connect to İnternet with Acer aspire 5750G

Tags: wireless, connection

I have problem with connection to Internet. I'm using W8 and it works properly but, when ı turn on Ubuntu I'm pushing Fn+F3(enabled-disabled) it says nothing. There are lots of İnternet connections via wifi. Nothing can see my computer when I'm in ubuntu. Is there something wrong with drivers. How can I solve it?

Comment: What **Ubuntu** version? **10.04**, **12.04**, **12,10**, etc.

Comment: Add details on what doesn't work for **wired**.

Comment: Define "Nothing can see my computer when I'm in ubuntu"; Define "Can't connect to Internet"; Explain what "Fn+F3" was supposed to do; Please show the output of `ifconfig -a` and of `lspci`. Which card do you have, do you know if the card is recognized and if its interface is created? Do you have some error message?

Comment: There is no any error message. Fn+F3 is a key combination that enable or disable wifi in my laptop. I don't know which card it is but I think there is a problem with driver.

Answer (score -1):

Its possible that **Windows-8** on exit/power-off disables a soft-key that prevents **WiFi**. Then , under **Ubuntu**, you are unable to access that soft-key toggle.

*It is sometimes in BIOS, but may be more under OS control.*

---

Needs more detail, to better answer.

Comment: My ethernet is Broadcam and ı have seen something in system setting. I clicked additional drivers. There was a Broadcam driver.  I try to turn it on but adminstration ask me to authenticate. What password I'm going to type there. It is the password that using at the opening of my computer with my name?

Comment: Yes, the **sudo** password if the same as your login.